# Are Mario & Luigi orphans?

Tags: mario-series

For one thing, I'm prettty sure the mustache'd duo is definitely human. No doubt.  But what I think I've never found out is whether or not they had parents.

IS there anything not non-canon that explains their birth, or better yet, their ancestry?

Are Mario & Luigi orphans? Or do they have parents we just don't know about?

Comment: I'd like it if people could explain downvotes

Comment: You expect coherent story?  From a Mario game?

Comment: @Retrosaur How is this a problem you are facing in a game?

Comment: Arqade is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices. If your question generally covers things such as …

Gameplay strategies and tactics
Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
Game mechanics and terminology
**Plot and characters in games**

Comment: Why does Mario rescue the princess every time?  Heck, why does Bowser kidnap her all the time?  WHY ARE WE KILLING GOOMBAS!?

Comment: I don't see any problem in this question, if you read the About page it says that you can ask about "Plot and characters in games"

Comment: @Retrosaur I downvoted because this question seems pointless. Also, it shows no research, since literally the first hit on Google for "Mario and Luigi parents" answers this question.

Comment: @Celta It does say that, but [we stop where the game canon stops and don't speculate any further.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/game-canon-questions-which-extend-beyond-the-context-of-the-story-and-its-materi) (Not that I know if this is speculative or not; apparently [Mama Mario](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mama_Mario) and [Papa](http://www.mariowiki.com/Papa) are things that exist.)

Comment: @badp it's not speculation if the game as the answer, even if a partial response

Comment: @Celta Yes, it does appear this rule doesn't apply here.

Comment: @badp then I think this question was judged rashly and without knowledge of the answer, this question should be considered valid according to the rules of the site

Comment: @Celta I _did_ reopen it.

Comment: Yes @badp ,I don't earn anything with it but thanks, I just want to see it being done right, and those who did it should not have much hurry to judge and think about their vote

Comment: Holy controversy Batman!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mario's parents are shown in Yoshi's Island, among other related [anime](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Issun-b%C5%8Dshi) and [comics](http://www.mariowiki.com/Family_Album_%27The_Early_Years%27).

Mama Mario:

> At the end of Super Mario World 2: Yoshi's Island, Mario and Luigi's mother made her first video game appearance. She is portrayed as a wide-set woman wearing a pink nightgown, and only her lower half and hands are seen.

Papa:

> The video game's artists portrayed him as a skinny man in a nightshirt of indeterminate color. Only his lower half and hands are seen.

The Mario Wiki has articles on both [Mama Mario](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mama_Mario) and [Papa](http://www.mariowiki.com/Papa), although there are a lot of references to the live action Super Mario Super Show, which is probably not canonical.

Likewise, the story is told differently in the [1993 Super Mario Bros movie](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Bros._(film)), where the two are orphaned when Luigi is still a baby.  Again, there were major rewrites to canon for the movie.

Answer (score 1):

Luigi and mario were babies when they flew on a stork to their parents. The ride got interrupted by the things on a broomstick and they fell on Yoshi island. The yoshis took care of them until they got older. That's why one of the first Mario games was Yoahi island.